# Qt, compiling program with dynamic libraried in the same path

Tags: qt, shared-libraries, qmake

I am trying to run my program in other computer without libraries. In *.pro file i added:

```
LIBS += -L"$$OUT_PWD/libs" -ltinyxml2
LIBS += -L"$$OUT_PWD/libs" -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_imgproc
LIBS += -L"$$OUT_PWD/libs" -lboost_system
```

Then i copied libraries to other computer to ~/myprogram/libs and binary file to ~/myprogram, but it can not load libraries

> ./gpAnalizer: error while loading shared libraries: libtinyxml2.so.2:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 2):

You should use [QMAKE_RPATHDIR](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake-rpathdir) variable.

Add the follow line to your `.pro` file:

```
QMAKE_RPATHDIR += $$OUT_PWD/libs
```

Of course this may work if  `$$OUT_PWD` is `~/myprogram/`. If not then replace it with actual path.